# How can I determine what type a (serialized and templatized) object received via socket is?

Tags: c++, sockets, protocol-buffers

I'm using `google protobuf` to implement a simple `Request/Response` based protocol.

A peer can receive via `socket` both `Request` and `Response`, (of course `serialized`) as `string`.

I'm using my own c++ socket implementation, so I implemented `operator>>` this way (the same is for `operator<<`) to receive data from a `socket` object:

```
 ...
template<class M>
void operator>>(M& m) throw (socks::exception) {
    std::string str;
    if (!this->recv(str)) {
        throw socks::exception(">> failed to retrieve stream via socket");
        return;
    }

    if (!m.ParseFromString(str))
        throw socks::exception(
                "failed to parse the received stream via socket");
}
```

So template argument `M` can be objects `Request` and `Response`.

```
// some lines from req_res.proto

message Request {
  required action_t action = 1; 
}

enum result_t {
   ...
}

message Response {
  required result_t result  = 1;
   ...
}
```

How can I determine whether I received a `Response` or a `Request` using `operator>>` this way?

```
my_socket_object s;
 ...
for (;;) {
  Request|Response r;
  s >> r;
   ...
}
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to put any possible message inside another high level message as a kind of tagged-union:

```
enum protocolmessage_t {
  Request = 1;
  Response = 2;
}

message ProtocolMessage {
  required protocolmessage_t type = 1; 

  optional Request request = 10;
  optional Response response = 11;
}
```

Then you would provide this `ProtocolMessage` as the `M` parameter to the `>>` operator and you can check the type and extract the corresponding value element.

An alternative way is to prefix every message with 1 byte for the type, make a switch on that type and then call your `>>` operator with the corresponding type.

Comment: Note that with Protobuf 2.6.0 (recently-released) you can use the new `oneof` feature to define a union, in which case you don't need a separate enum.

Answer (score 2):

You can have one basic `Message` object and extend all other types used in your protocol from it:

```
message Message {
    extensions 100 to max;
}

message Request {
    extends Message {
        optional Request request = 100;
    }
    required action_t action = 1; 
}

message Response {
    extends Message {
        optional Response response = 101;
    }
    required result_t result  = 1;
}
```

This is a bit more elegant, self contained and easier to extend, than the *discriminator/union* solution proposed in the other answer IMHO.

---

You can use this technique even further to structure e.g. your `Request`/`Response` messages like this

```
message Request {
    extends Message {
        optional Request request = 100;
    }

    extensions 100 to max;
}

message Action1 {
    extends Request {
        optional Action1 action1 = 100;
    }
    optional int32 param1 = 1;
    optional int32 param2 = 2;
}

message Action2 {
    extends Request {
        optional Action2 action2 = 101;
    }
    optional int32 param1 = 1;
    optional int32 param2 = 2;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, this seems nicer than the union. How do you discriminate then, will protobuf generate a subclass relationship?

Comment: @JanickBernet The protobuf compiler will generate appropriate templates functions and an extension identifier for you. There are separate classes generated for the messages as usual, think more of a _has a_ than an _is a_ relationship. You can see more how to deal with it in this [documentation section](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#extension).